# Send UI Notification from VUEX Store's action

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, alertify, vuex-modules

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-alertify to send notification when my API request has been succesful inside action of the store:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import {
  API_SUCCESS,
  API_FAILURE,
} from './types/common';


Vue.use(Vuex);

/**
 * Common State
 * @property {boolean} isProgress - if async operation is in progress
 */
const state = {
  isProgress: false,
};

/**
 * Common Getters
 * @property {boolean} isProgress - Checks if the async op is in progress
 */
export const getters = {
  isProgress: state =>
    state.isProgress,
};

/**
 * Common Actions
 */
const actions = {

  [API_SUCCESS]: ({}, message) => {
    console.log(this);
    this._vm.$alertify.success(message);
  },
  [API_FAILURE]: ({}, message) => {
    this._vm.$alertify.failure(message || 'Failure');
  },
};

/**
 * Common Mutations
 */
const mutations = {

  [PROGRESS_START]: (state) => {
    state.isProgress = true;
  },
  [PROGRESS_STOP]: (state) => {
    state.isProgress = false;
  },
};


export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,     
});
```

#### I'm dispatching my action from components @click method like this

```
persist() {
  const { $store, } = this;

  $store.dispatch(ca.PROGRESS_START);
  $store.dispatch(ca.API_SUCCESS, 'Hey little!');
},
```

And it fails with on this line
**this._vm.$alertify.success(message);**

with the error
[image]

however If I enable debugger and from console type the same command - it works and I see $alertify notification on my browser.

#### What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Vuex actions has no access to your main vue instance that's why.

Comment: your best bet would be vuex's plugins to listen to any store values mutations and fire accordingly for your case https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/plugins.html